# Outputting list of products as well as who has bought those products

Tags: mysql

Like the table to suggests, I wish to output a list of all products, but at the same time a list of who have bought each prouct.

My data is structued as follows

```
products
=================
|prodId |prod   |
=================
|1      |hat    |
|2      |shirt  |
|3      |watch  |
|4      |cream  |
|5      |pizza  |
=================


orders
=========================
|ordID  |prodID |cust   |
=========================
|1      |2      |paul   |
|2      |4      |paul   |
|3      |4      |bob    |
|4      |5      |jane   |
|5      |4      |sarah  |
=========================
```

And I wish to receive this result, where in if no customers have purchased it, it will be `null`

```
=================
|prod   |cust   |
=================
|hat    |null   |
|shirt  |paul   |
|watch  |null   |
|cream  |paul   |
|cream  |bob    |
|cream  |sarah  |
|pizza  |jane   |
=================
```

Comment: Try a google search for "sql join"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.prod, o.cust, count(o.*) count_of
FROM products as p
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders as o ON p.prodid = o.prodid
GROUP BY prod, cust
```

To arrive at a list of al products start with `from products` then use an `OUTER` join which permits unmatched rows to be returned as well as the rows that do have a match.

Then the `group by` reduces the list to unique combinations, and it enables aggregations such a count.

Answer (score 0):

The below query should do the job

```
select p.prod, o.cust from products p left outer join orders o on p.prodId = o.prodId;
```